# What kind of services does ESXI SLP port advertise to locally connected hosts?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter, vmware-server

I got enthusiastic about the last exploitations of ESXI CVE-2021-21974 (heap overflow exploitation). After researching the SLP service, which is the weak point in this CVE, I tried to turn it off, after which everything still was working perfectly fine, so I had a logical question, what kind of services SLP port on ESXI advertises about?

In addition, I would like to ask how is it possible to send an SLP request manually.

Answer (score 1):

you can download SLP software from https://www.openslp.org for a number of OSs (including Windows and Linux). That includes a CLI tool called slptool which you can use to send SLP discovery messages.

ESXi uses SLP to announce its CIM monitoring service.